# Sitecore 9.3 installation error - Creating Shard - SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe returned a non-zero exit code

Tags: sql, sitecore, sharding

I have Sql Server 2016 SP2.

Everthing is working fine some datbases also created under SQL then on shard creation got this error.

```
[ XConnectXP0_SetServicesCertStorePe... : FilePermissions ---------------------]
[XConnectXP0_SetServicesCertStorePermissions]:[Allow] NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
[XConnectXP0_SetServicesCertStorePermissions]:[Path] C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\de9191ad2f8c4a7a919ff6522f9b2f7c_380b148d-8c36-42ab-a690-8f1d118ba921
[XConnectXP0_SetServicesCertStorePermissions]:[Rights] Read
[XConnectXP0_SetServicesCertStorePermissions]:[Inherit] None
[XConnectXP0_SetServicesCertStorePermissions]:[Propagate] None

[------------- XConnectXP0_CleanShards : Command -----------------------------]
[ShardingTool - Clean]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore134xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe

[------------ XConnectXP0_CreateShards : Command -----------------------------]
[ShardingTool - Create]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore134xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
Command C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore134xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (2)
[TIME] 00:32:24
Command C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore134xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (2)
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was resolved by replacing `double backslashes` in **Microsoft SQL Server instance** value with `single backslash`.

[image]

It seems that issue is with slashes escaping. Single and double backslashes both work fine in `powershell` *(because of this you see some created sitecore databases)*, but double backslash does not work in `Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe`.